# Can't get Algolia search to work from my react-native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, search, algolia

I have just started a fresh React Native project and would like to implement Algolia as the search component. After going through the docs and hours of head scratching i can't get it to work.

Is there someone who can help me get this thing going?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/reactnative';
import { InstantSearch } from 'react-instantsearch-native';

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  'xxx',
  'xxxx'
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safe: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#252b33',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
});

class App extends React.Component {
  root = {
    Root: View,
    props: {
      style: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <InstantSearch
            searchClient={searchClient}
            indexName="Test"
            root={this.root}
          >
            <SearchBox />
            <InfiniteHits />
          </InstantSearch>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is algolia the right way to go for React Native developers?

[syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN1Xc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `algoliasearch/reactnative` is a thing. You want `import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite`.

Did you start with the `create-instancesearch-app` `npx` [script](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/#build-a-simple-ui)? It creates a lot of the boilerplate for your React Native app for you.

I haven't dug into Algolia for Native coding, but there are several examples available. Seems like the biggest difference is you can't use the widgets provided in the InstantSearch library and instead need to use [connectors](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/#using-connectors-instead-of-widgets) to tie to Native components like `FlastList`.

[That page](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/) walks you through the whole process of getting something up and running.

Comment: Hi! So i actually got my Algolia Search app to work using the create-instancesearch-app script :)